# Софт для введения учета с СУБД в банках

Tags: база-данных

хотел спросить как называется софт который используют в банках для введения учета

пример:

человек взял кредит-банк инвестировал
и как сотрудники банка ориентируется в более 100к кредиторов и 100к инвестиций и как он понимает когда и кто должен возвращать деньги

Comment: У многих банков собственные разработки. Хотя наверняка есть и продукты которые используются несколькими банками

Comment: Если упрощённо, то это база данных с приложением, которое сообщает о событии в нужный момент времени. Называться может по-разному.

Comment: С точки зрения БД вообще никаких проблем. Достаточно к счету клиента или другой сущности (например конкретному кредиту) хранить дату следующего погашения. И дальше запрашиваем все записи с датой меньшей данной. Это любые БД умеют

Comment: Как правило это собственная разработка, на основе Java + Oracle (Или любая другая уровня Enterprise БД) В учреждениях поменьше используют или Microsoft Dynamics AX или в Российском / СНГ сегменте зачастую 1С